# Can I use JAAS config for hive connection without system property

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, kerberos, jaas

In my application I am using hive connection and Oracle connection, both of them using Kerberos authentication. I will need to use 2 different keytab files for each connection. Is it possible to use Jaas configuration file in hive without using or setting system properties?